# How to plot this equation?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot the equation shown in the image, but I'm not sure how to apply the Galois Seq. "gf()" here.
Can you please help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f306.png)

[image: eqn 1]

[image: eqn 2]

```
 clear all
    close all
    clc
    %%
    Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
    T = 1/Fs;                     % Sampling period
    L = 1024;                     % Length of signal
    t = 2*(0:L-1)*T;              % Time vector
    signal = 0;
    m = 5;
    for k=1:((2^m)-1)
     g = gf(2^m);
     signal = signal + g(k).*exp(1i*2*pi*k*t)/((2^m)-1);
    end
    figure
    subplot(2,2,1)
    plot(t,signal)
    title('signal')
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Do you have output/errors out of that? Did you check how to use `gf()` in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gf.html)?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the expected magnitude waveform, but I can't seem to get the same plot (I added the expected waveform above). I also keep getting errors in the loop section.

Comment: It's important that you improve your question by adding also the output of your code, so others can reproduce and compare.

Comment: The expected output waveform picture is attached in the question

Comment: You said you "keep getting errors in the loop section", it would be good to know what those are. In my case, I don't have MATLAB, but I have Octave (the open-source clone) so in order to help you, I should be able to know that I'm having the same errors as yours, or errors due to the (small but existent) differences between Octave and MATLAB.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.